# FOSS License compatibility

Tags: software, licensing, open-source-software, foss

I have been struggling to understand license compatibility and how it manifests.

Two examples:

1. I have a program to which i wrote the codebase. This codebase then dynamically links to two different open source libraries. One is licensed under Apache v2 and the other under LGPL 2.1. Can i distribute the program considering that I comply with Apache v2 and LGPL v2.1 requirements? Or because Apache v2 and LGPLv2.1 are incompatible my program cannot link to these two libraries?
2. I use the Eclipse Framework (EPLv2) and dynamically link to an Apache v2 library. Can i distribute the program considering I comply with EPLv2 and Apache v2 requirements?

Comment: Cross-posting on other sites ([opensource.stanchange.com](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/13231/15273)) is [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).